# Javascript - Convert timestamp into milliseconds for Highcharts Y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please help me in converting the string into time `format[Hr:Min:Sec]`

Here is my piece

```
seriesData_1.push(parseFloat($(this).attr('myVar')));
```

I have tried changing this to:

```
seriesData_1.push(Date.parse("1-1-1" + ($(this).attr('myVar'))));
```

but no luck. The `myVar` will be holding the value `20:57:13`

**Update :** I was so dumb in Highcharts & Javascript and with Stackoverflow guidance, I got what I want.

Here it is. I have got a series `myVar` holding values like `20:57:13` etc in `Hr:Min:Sec` format which needed to be plotted in `Y axis`. Got to know that we have got `datetime` type in Y axis which can plot the graph for you. But for that you need to get your timestamp converted into milliseconds.

And this is what I have done for that

```
yourtime = $(this).attr('myVar');
hms = yourtime.split(':');
msecs = hms[0] * 3600000 + hms[1] * 60000 + hms[2]*1000;
seriesData_1.push(msecs);
```

Now I have got it converted into milliseconds, to get this plotted in Y axis with `H:M:S` format, you need to use `dateTimeLabelFormats` under `y axis` as below

```
            type: 'datetime',

            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M:%S',
            hour: '%H:%M:%S'
            },
```

To get your tooltip aligned with `H:M:S` format, add this

```
            tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                      var main = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +'</b>';
                      s = Math.floor(this.y / 1000);
                      m = Math.floor(s / 60);
                      s = s % 60;
                      h = Math.floor(m / 60);
                      m = m % 60;
                      h = h % 24;
                      if (h < 9) h = "0" + h;
                      if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
                      if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
                      return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br>' + '<span style="color:green">Value-</span>' + [h, m, s].join(':');
                    }
            },
```

Hope this helps for the newbies like me :)

Comment: And what doe this have to do with Ajax? Where is the XMLHttpRequest object in the code?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but isn't `20:57:13` already in `Hr:Min:Sec` format?

Comment: @epascarello this code was in ajax module under highcharts

Comment: @Amadan yes this is in the same format. But when I plot the highcharts graph, it picks up only the hr column. So I thought that it might be in string and that needed to convert to timestamp with date parser

Comment: Because you can only have numbers for Y axis. Convert your date into seconds (`hms = val.split(':'); secs = hms[0] * 3600 + hms[1] * 60 + hms[2]`) and use that.

Comment: My Y axis is of format 
`yAxis: [{
                //tickInterval: 0.05 ,
                //max:100,
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                        second: '%H:%M:%S',
                        minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                        hour: '%H:%M:%S',
                        day: '%H:%M:%S',
                        week: '%H:%M:%S',
                        month: '%H:%M:%S',
                        year: '%H:%M:%S'
                 },`

Comment: I'm trying to follow the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268170/plotting-seconds-minutes-and-hours-on-the-yaxis-with-highcharts

Comment: You can have time on the Y axis by using `yAxis.formatter`, to convert seconds back into `H:M:S`.

Comment: @Amadan If that works out, can you please help me that in the code

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Or show what already have done in your website?

Comment: Pawel, thank you. I got what I desired for.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, convert series into seconds:

```
var hms = val.split(':');
var secs = hms[0] * 3600 + hms[1] * 60 + hms[2];
series.push(secs);
```

Then set the `yAxis.formatter` to this function to restore the `H:M:S` on the axis:

```
function() {
  var h = Math.floor(this.value / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor(this.value / 60) % 60;
  var s = this.value % 60;
  if (h < 9) h = "0" + h;
  if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
  if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
  return [h, m, s].join(':');
}
```

Messing about with datetime is counterproductive, since it is never meant to hold dateless time.

(Disclaimer: all this deduced from the API description, I have no familiarity with Highchart.)

Comment: My chart is not getting displayed in the browser. Have to think some other way around.. Thanks for your help Amadan