# represent time in highcharts

Tags: javascript, time, highcharts

i'am creating a highcharts that represent time ex : (02:00:00) on the yAxis and Dates on xAxis but i didn't found how to change the yAxis series type to do it .
 here is my code :

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: ["02:00:00","03:00:00","01:00:00"]
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: the series should be Integer , can u create a plunker or fiddle so that will be easy to fix

Comment: @gayathri i know you should put an integer  , i can send the time on seconds format but how to reformat the seconds to time on the highchars so it can be displayed as time .

Comment: refer this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268170/plotting-seconds-minutes-and-hours-on-the-yaxis-with-highcharts

Comment: You need to convert dates in the preprocessing. So load data, use loops and parser (like Date.parse or operation on strings and call Date.UTC()) then push new data in Highcharts and init the chart.